# Combining AVG and COUNT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm used to doing this kind of query in SQL Server. I'm out of my depth with MySQL.

What I hope I'm communicating is that I want to group the `noise_detail` records according to `monitor_id` and hour of day ACROSS A RANGE OF DATES, but on each row, I then want the average of the `noise_level` column for each aggregated row and then an average for the `count(*)` of rows within each aggregated row.

Here is some sample data of the raw events we're tracking.

OY VEH. HEAVILY EDITED =AGAIN= TO EXPLAIN THE SOURCE DATA...

Each row in this sample data represents a 'noise event' from dozens of monitors, each coded as 'SEA01, SEA02, SEA03, etc.) They each take dozens of readings every hour, every day.

It is very important to know the -average- number of events that happen at 3AM over a range of dates. So: take the COUNT(*) of events at SEA01 on Jan 1 at 3AM, then the COUNT(*) of events at SEA01 on Jan 2 at 3AM, etc. and then give me the -average- for all those dates.

And we also need to know the average noise level for each hour at each monitor. So similarly, take the AVG(noise_level) of events at SEA01 on Jan 1 at 3AM, then the AVERAGE(noise_level) of events at SEA01 on Jan 2 at 3AM, etc. and then give me the -average- for all those dates.

```
ID    monitor_id    time            noise_level 
393211  SEA14   2016-03-22 15:39:00 79
393245  SEA11   2016-03-05 07:20:00 81.6
338262  SEA15   2016-02-28 19:44:00 80.4
338263  SEA14   2016-02-28 19:55:00 74.2
338264  SEA14   2016-02-28 19:54:00 81.5
338265  SEA14   2016-02-28 19:44:00 73.4
338266  SEA13   2016-02-28 19:54:00 81
338267  SEA13   2016-02-28 19:43:00 94.3
338268  SEA12   2016-02-28 19:43:00 80.2
338269  SEA11   2016-02-28 19:53:00 89
338270  SEA11   2016-02-28 19:43:00 89.5
338271  SEA09   2016-02-28 19:43:00 75.2
338272  SEA09   2016-02-28 19:42:00 73.9
338273  SEA09   2016-02-28 19:41:00 85.1
338588  SEA28   2016-02-29 05:04:00 83.3
338589  SEA22   2016-02-29 05:04:00 82.7
338590  SEA21   2016-02-29 05:04:00 82.9
338591  SEA20   2016-02-29 05:04:00 84.1
338592  SEA19   2016-02-29 05:03:00 88.6
338593  SEA18   2016-02-29 05:03:00 85.5
338594  SEA17   2016-02-29 05:03:00 86.6
338749  SEA14   2016-02-28 20:43:00 83
```

So what I need is to have it look like this: (NOTE: this is a sample from the complete report it is NOT culled from the above subset.)

```
NOISE  REPORT FROM 01/01/2016 - 06/30/2016 SHOWING AVGS FOR EACH HOUR
=================================================
                 avg              avg
monitor_id  hour num_events/hr    noise_level for each hour
SEA11       03AM 12               70.3
SEA11       04AM 55               81.6
SEA11       05AM 27               83.2
SEA11       06AM 16               79.6
....etc.
SEA12       03AM 21               72.7
SEA12       04AM 45               83.1
SEA12       05AM 17               87.9
SEA12       06AM 26               77.6
....etc.
```

...so I need one row for each monitor/hour  with the average # of events which occurred during that hour across a range of dates and then the -average- noise_level, again for all the events which occur during each hour across a range of dates.

EG. Line 6 'The average number of events which occurred at 4AM from Jan 1 - Jun 30 for Monitor SEA12'.

Here is what I have so far, it's 'pseudo-code' which obviously won't work, but I hope it expresses what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT time, 
       monitor_id, 
       AVG( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM noise_detail nc WHERE nc.monitor_id = n.monitor_id ) AS average_number_of_events,  // avg number of events at X'o'clock
       SELECT AVG(noise_level) FROM noise_detail nl WHERE nl.monitor_id = n.monitor_id) AS average_noise_level  // avg noise level at X'o'clock
FROM noise_detail AS n
GROUP by monitor_id, SUBSTR(time,12,2)  // group by monitor and X'o'clock (the hour of the day in 24 hr format)
```

Comment: only in that I'm using this within Wordpress and PHP.  If it's not relevant, I can certainly remove it.

Comment: Can you supply some sample data from each table, just to get a jist of what you're working with?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: The "average number of events/hour" for a one hour interval is the TOTAL number of events in that hour.

Comment: @symcbean no. I'm obviously not explaining this clearly. See ANOTHER edit above.

Comment: The code you've shown us won't produce the results you have shown us. How do you get a value of 12 for sea11 at 3am and a value of 55 at 4am? Show your working.

Comment: @symcbean Well, the code -doesn't- work. I could show you the SQL Server version if that would help. I can't show the full data set--it's literally 100,000 records. Please see the edits to the sample data above. 4AM means 'The average number of events which occurred at 4AM from Jan 1 - Jun 30 for Monitor SEA12'. Hope that's clearer.

Comment: Or in english: "Give me a subtotal for each monitor and each hour of the day showing the average number of events and the avg noise level"

Comment: `I could show you the SQL Server version if that would help` If you have this working in sql-sever code then: **yes absolutely this will help**

Comment: I would prefer to see the result from the subset, and sqlfiddle of same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a second attempt. Note the data used is different than in the question, See this version working here at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08ea73/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE noise_detail 
    (`ID` int, `monitor_id` varchar(5), `time` datetime, `noise_level` int)
;

INSERT INTO noise_detail 
    (`ID`, `monitor_id`, `time`, `noise_level`)
VALUES
    (338271, 'SEA09', '2016-02-24 18:43:00', 75.2),
    (338272, 'SEA09', '2016-02-24 18:42:00', 73.9),
    (338273, 'SEA09', '2016-02-24 18:41:00', 85.1),

    (338271, 'SEA09', '2016-02-24 19:43:00', 75.2),
    (338272, 'SEA09', '2016-02-24 19:42:00', 73.9),
    (338273, 'SEA09', '2016-02-24 19:41:00', 85.1),

    (338271, 'SEA09', '2016-02-25 19:43:00', 75.2),
    (338272, 'SEA09', '2016-02-25 19:42:00', 73.9),
    (338273, 'SEA09', '2016-02-25 19:41:00', 85.1),

    (338271, 'SEA09', '2016-02-26 18:43:00', 75.2),
    (338272, 'SEA09', '2016-02-26 18:42:00', 73.9),
    (338273, 'SEA09', '2016-02-26 18:41:00', 85.1),

    (338271, 'SEA09', '2016-02-26 19:43:00', 75.2),
    (338272, 'SEA09', '2016-02-26 19:42:00', 73.9),
    (338273, 'SEA09', '2016-02-26 19:41:00', 85.1),

    (338271, 'SEA09', '2016-02-28 19:43:00', 75.2),
    (338272, 'SEA09', '2016-02-28 19:42:00', 73.9),
    (338273, 'SEA09', '2016-02-28 19:41:00', 85.1),

    (338271, 'SEA09', '2016-02-28 19:43:00', 75.2),
    (338272, 'SEA09', '2016-02-28 19:42:00', 73.9),
    (338273, 'SEA09', '2016-02-28 19:41:00', 85.1)
;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT
       monitor_id
     , HOUR(time) 
     , COUNT(*)                             as tot_events_in_hour
     , COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(time)) as av_events_ph
     , AVG(noise_level)                     AS av_noise_level_in_hour 
     , AVG(noise_level) / COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(time)) AS av_noise_level_ph
FROM noise_detail n
GROUP BY
       monitor_id
     , HOUR(time) 
ORDER BY
       monitor_id
     , HOUR(time)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08ea73/4/0)**:

```
| monitor_id | HOUR(time) | tot_events_in_hour | av_events_ph | av_noise_level_in_hour | av_noise_level_ph |
|------------|------------|--------------------|--------------|------------------------|-------------------|
|      SEA09 |         18 |                  6 |            3 |                     78 |                39 |
|      SEA09 |         19 |                 15 |         3.75 |                     78 |              19.5 |
```

---

It is a common misconception that date/time data is stored in a human readable format. It is highly likely that the column `time` is not stored that way and hence substr() which is designed for strings isn't appropriate to determine the hour of day. You need date/time functions for this instead.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e51200/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE noise_detail 
    (`ID` int, `monitor_id` varchar(5), `time` datetime, `noise_level` int)
;

INSERT INTO noise_detail 
    (`ID`, `monitor_id`, `time`, `noise_level`)
VALUES
    (393211, 'SEA14', '2016-03-22 15:39:00', 79),
    (393245, 'SEA11', '2016-03-05 07:20:00', 81.6),
    (338262, 'SEA15', '2016-02-28 19:44:00', 80.4),
    (338263, 'SEA14', '2016-02-28 19:55:00', 74.2),
    (338264, 'SEA14', '2016-02-28 19:54:00', 81.5),
    (338265, 'SEA14', '2016-02-28 19:44:00', 73.4),
    (338266, 'SEA13', '2016-02-28 19:54:00', 81),
    (338267, 'SEA13', '2016-02-28 19:43:00', 94.3),
    (338268, 'SEA12', '2016-02-28 19:43:00', 80.2),
    (338269, 'SEA11', '2016-02-28 19:53:00', 89),
    (338270, 'SEA11', '2016-02-28 19:43:00', 89.5),
    (338271, 'SEA09', '2016-02-28 19:43:00', 75.2),
    (338272, 'SEA09', '2016-02-28 19:42:00', 73.9),
    (338273, 'SEA09', '2016-02-28 19:41:00', 85.1),
    (338588, 'SEA28', '2016-02-29 05:04:00', 83.3),
    (338589, 'SEA22', '2016-02-29 05:04:00', 82.7),
    (338590, 'SEA21', '2016-02-29 05:04:00', 82.9),
    (338591, 'SEA20', '2016-02-29 05:04:00', 84.1),
    (338592, 'SEA19', '2016-02-29 05:03:00', 88.6),
    (338593, 'SEA18', '2016-02-29 05:03:00', 85.5),
    (338594, 'SEA17', '2016-02-29 05:03:00', 86.6),
    (338749, 'SEA14', '2016-02-28 20:43:00', 83)
;
```

**First Query Suggested**:

```
SELECT
       monitor_id
     , HOUR(time) 
     , COUNT(*) as number_of_events
     , AVG(noise_level) AS average_noise_level 
FROM noise_detail n
GROUP BY
       monitor_id
     , HOUR(time) 
ORDER BY
       monitor_id
     , HOUR(time)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e51200/2/0)**:

```
| monitor_id | HOUR(time) | number_of_events | average_noise_level |
|------------|------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      SEA09 |         19 |                3 |                  78 |
|      SEA11 |          7 |                1 |                  82 |
|      SEA11 |         19 |                2 |                89.5 |
|      SEA12 |         19 |                1 |                  80 |
|      SEA13 |         19 |                2 |                87.5 |
|      SEA14 |         15 |                1 |                  79 |
|      SEA14 |         19 |                3 |             76.3333 |
|      SEA14 |         20 |                1 |                  83 |
|      SEA15 |         19 |                1 |                  80 |
|      SEA17 |          5 |                1 |                  87 |
|      SEA18 |          5 |                1 |                  86 |
|      SEA19 |          5 |                1 |                  89 |
|      SEA20 |          5 |                1 |                  84 |
|      SEA21 |          5 |                1 |                  83 |
|      SEA22 |          5 |                1 |                  83 |
|      SEA28 |          5 |                1 |                  83 |
```

Comment: No, that was actually where I started. That just gives the total # of events for each monitor/hour, I need the -average- number of events that happen at 3AM across a range of dates. Please see my new heavy edits above. It needs some sort of SELECT AVG within the main SELECT.

Comment: Your edits just confuse further imho. The "trick" to clarity in such cases is to align your sample data to the `expected result`, one should be able to derive the expected result from the sample. I don't see that here. I will attempt something else and maybe that will help.

Comment: You're probably right. It will take a while to prepare a 'realistic' example dataset of ins and outs. I'd hoped to avoid that as I've noticed questions literally fall of this forum if one doesn't get it right immediately. I don't want this to sound snippy, but I literally did not realise it would be so hard to explain or 'grok'. Perhaps because I work this stuff every day. Thanks for your help. Cheers.

Comment: added second attempt, does this assist at all?

Comment: I -think- this may work... or be a LOT closer than I've gotten. I can't test with live dataset until tomorrow. Back then.

Comment: You have both 'solutions' titled 'Query 1'. The first of these is the winning solution. I'd suggest relabeling the second one to avoid confusing future viewers.

Comment: Thanks. I changed to first siggestion heading (those headings get generated by sqldiddle).

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT time, monitor_id, 
       COUNT(*) as number_of_events,
       AVG(noise_level) AS average_noise_level 
FROM noise_detail nd
GROUP by monitor_id, SUBSTR(time, 12, 2);
```

I'm not sure what `substr(time, 12, 2)` is supposed to be doing.  If `time` is stored as a string, then fine. If as a date/time data type, then use the functionality specific to those types.

Comment: substr(time, 12, 2) is to make the subtotal (group) by -hour-. Your solution doesn't help me. I need the average number of events for each monitor/hour aggregate. See my example data which I hope is clearer.